# How many people die in each episode of Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I'm trying to do a time series analysis on the total number of deaths (of not just important characters but everyone in general) per epsisode of Game of thrones for a course project. I was wondering if there was a statistic/dataset on total number of deaths per episode per season. I've come to know from Washington Post Dataset (May 2019) that total number is 5863 (latest) and I know per season. But I needed per episode as well. If anyone has a resource, that'd be amazing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The video does not differentiate with episode, it just has on screen killings. I was looking for a proper division with episodes for my analysis! Thanks!

Comment: I voted to re-open since this is a distinct question from the two linked questions (though one does have a throwaway line that that information would be cool) and does not have an answer (too nonspecific since those questions don't require absolute numbers) in either of them, and both already have accepted answers, so they're not likely to get any activity to answer your question. Don't get your hopes up, though: it's easier and more rewarding for people to moderate than to answer.

Comment: @Shamshiel I don't appreciate the dig at me for closing the question as a duplicate. It's fine for people to have differing opinions but don't do personal attacks at them for it.

Comment: It wasn’t a dig at you because I don’t pay attention to who does what. It’s an endemic problem on SF&F and the end-state of many community-driven moderation systems.

Comment: It won't let me add an answer, but this site ( https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/entertainment/game-of-thrones/?utm_term=.36eb18d94f30&noredirect=on ) has been updated to reflect some of season 8 sofar...

Comment: @Cinderhaze:Thanks! Appreciate it really!

Comment: if this question won't be unlocked, you may re-create it and self-answer it https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer with the link of @Cinderhaze

Comment: Is this supposed to be only deaths on screen or does it include the number of reported casualties in various battles and massacres, etc.?  Named characters only or nameless spear carriers?

Comment: @M.A.Golding : On screen deaths of every character (both named and un - named).